# SQL Query 3 Tables with more than one Join condition

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

Hello Stackoverflow Comunity,

I have 3 Tables in Excel and want to connect it (as in Access)with left join Query:

`1 Table "ClientUnique" has: Client, Name1 and Delieveryadress`

`2 Table "Backlog" has: Client, Name1 and Delieveryadress, Backlog`

`3 Table "ThisWeek" has: Client, Name1 and Delieveryadress, ThisWeek`
I want to make a sql query that retrives:

`Client, Name1 and Delieveryadress, Backlog, ThisWeek`.

When I make join connection with one "column" it works

```
SQLQuery = "SELECT" & _ 
                "a.[Client] " & _ 
                ",a.[name1] " & _
                ",a.[Deliveryadress] " & _
                ",b.[CountThisweek] " & _
                ",c.[CountBacklog] " & _
            "FROM " & _
                "([ClientUnique$] AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN [Thisweek$] AS c ON a.[Deliveryadress] = c.[Deliveryadress]) " & _
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN [Backlog$] AS b ON a.[Deliveryadress] = b.[Deliveryadress] " & _
            "GROUP BY " &_ 
                "a.[Client] " &_
                ",a.[name1] " &_
                ",a.[Deliveryadress] " &_
                ",b.[CountThisweek] " &_
                ",c.[CountBacklog]"
```

but if I try to use more than one join condition it dosen't work?

```
SQLQuery1 = "SELECT" & _ 
                "a.[Client] " & _ 
                ",a.[name1] " & _
                ",a.[Deliveryadress] " & _
                ",b.[CountThisweek] " & _
                ",c.[CountBacklog] " & _
            "FROM " & _
                "([ClientUnique$] AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN [Thisweek$] AS c" & _
                "ON a.[Deliveryadress] = c.[Deliveryadress] AND " & _
                "a.[Client] = c.[Client] AND " & _
                "a.[name1] = c.[name1]) " & _
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN [Backlog$] AS b " & 
                "ON a.[Deliveryadress] = b.[Deliveryadress] AND " & _
                "a.[Client] = b.[Client] AND " & _
                "a.[name1] = b.[name1]" & _
            "GROUP BY " &_ 
                "a.[Client] " &_
                ",a.[name1] " &_
                ",a.[Deliveryadress] " &_
                ",b.[CountThisweek] " &_
                ",c.[CountBacklog]"
```

Can you please see the second code and give me a hint what is wrong with it.

Comment: then the conditions don't fit, you should test your queries in access and add only one condition at a time, to see which is the culprit

Comment: @nbk,
in Access works fine with three join conditions.  I'm trying to implement it in Excel using ADODB. With one works fine but adding second and third does not work:(

Comment: if you only add condition2 without 3 it stll doesn't give any result? i never heard of it, so i am curious

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Does it give an error - in which case what is the error message? Does it not return the data you expect - in which case please update your question with sample data for all the tables involved and the result you expect to see based on that sample data

Comment: @nbk, yes it doesn't work either. I get this error massage:
An error occurred after the connection was established.
Error number: -2147217904
No value was specified for at least one required parameter.

Comment: maybe only a typo in your tables try only a.[name1] = b.[name1] and so on with out the rest

Comment: @nbk and NickW, I found mistake in my code :) It was formating error.  One space before " was missing. I have prepeared a worksheet with dummy data. And here it works :). 
I'm adding it to the forum maybe someone need it too. I have adapted Some code from "wiseowl youtube".
Thx a lot for your hints :)

Answer (score 0):

When preparing the file for posting, I decided to write it again rather than copy it from my "problem" file. And I found the mistake. In one place there was a space missing before " which caused the code to be misinterpreted.

Unfortunately I don't know where I can attach the file so I am attaching 2 Subs that works. Maybe someone want to use it:)

Thank you nbk for the time you took to help me. Your approach with eliminating Joins helped:)

```
Sub SQL_uniqueclient()
Dim SQLQuery As String
Dim shsql As Worksheet
SQLQuery = "SELECT " & _
                "a.[Client] " & _
                ", a.[name1] " & _
                ", a.[Deliveryadress] " & _
                ", b.[CountThisweek] " & _
                ", c.[CountBacklog] " & _
            "FROM ([ClientUnique$] AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN [Thisweek$] AS c " & _
            "ON a.[Deliveryadress] = c.[Deliveryadress] " & _
            "and a.[Client] = c.[Client] " & _
            "and a.[Name1] = c.[Name1]) " & _
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN [Backlog$] AS b " & _
            "ON a.[Deliveryadress] = b.[Deliveryadress] " & _
            "and a.[Client] = b.[Client] " & _
            "and a.[Name1] = b.[Name1] " & _
            "GROUP BY " & _
                "a.[Client] " & _
                ", a.[name1] " & _
                ", a.[Deliveryadress] " & _
                ", b.[CountThisweek] " & _
                ", c.[CountBacklog]"


Set shsql = ShResult 'named Worksheet where the Result will be copied. 
    SQLExecute SQLQuery, shsql
Set shsql = Nothing
End Sub


'###########################################################
'This Sub runs SQL Query and put result in Table "Result"  #
'Most of it where copied from WiseOwl Tutorial             #
############################################################

Sub SQLExecute(SQLQuery As String, shsql As Worksheet)
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset


    If SQLQuery = "" Then
        MsgBox _
            Prompt:="Es wurde keine SQL abfragen übergeben", _
            Buttons:=vbCritical, _
            Title:="SQL String fehlt"
        Exit Sub
    End If


    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';"
    
'Try to open the connection, exit the subroutine if this fails
    On Error GoTo EndPoint
    conn.Open
    
'If anything fails after this point, close the connection before exiting
    On Error GoTo CloseConnection

'SQL Abfrage wird ausgeführt
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    
    rs.ActiveConnection = conn
    rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
    rs.Source = SQLQuery    'Use the query string that we passed into the procedure
    
'Try to open the recordset to return the results of the query
    rs.Open
    On Error GoTo CloseRecordset
    
'Inhalt in der tabelle "shsql" löschen
    shsql.Cells.ClearContents

'Header ermitteln
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        shsql.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
    Next i

'Daten aus Recordset in "shsql" ab "A2" kopieren
    shsql.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

'Spalltenbreite aufs Inhalt anpassen
    shsql.Columns("A:F").AutoFit

    'Close the recordset and connection
    rs.Close
    conn.Close
    'Free resources used by the recordset and connection
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing
    
    'Exit here to make sure that the error handling code does not run
    Exit Sub
  
'========================================================================
'ERROR HANDLERS
'========================================================================
CloseRecordset:
'If the recordset is opened successfully but a runtime error occurs later we end up here
    rs.Close
    conn.Close
    
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing
    
    Debug.Print SQLQuery
    
    MsgBox _
        Prompt:="An error occurred after the recordset was opened." & vbNewLine _
            & vbNewLine & "Error number: " & Err.Number _
            & vbNewLine & "Error description: " & Err.Description, _
        Buttons:=vbCritical, _
        Title:="Error After Recordset Open"
    
    Exit Sub

CloseConnection:
'If the connection is opened successfully but a runtime error occurs later we end up here
    conn.Close
    
    Set conn = Nothing
    
    Debug.Print SQLQuery
    
    MsgBox _
        Prompt:="An error occurred after the connection was established." & vbNewLine _
            & vbNewLine & "Error number: " & Err.Number _
            & vbNewLine & "Error description: " & Err.Description, _
        Buttons:=vbCritical, _
        Title:="Error After Connection Open"
    
    Exit Sub
    
'If the connection failed to open we end up here
EndPoint:
    MsgBox _
        Prompt:="The connection failed to open." & vbNewLine _
            & vbNewLine & "Error number: " & Err.Number _
            & vbNewLine & "Error description: " & Err.Description, _
        Buttons:=vbCritical, _
        Title:="Connection Error"
End Sub
`
```